# Special symbols as patterns in bash case statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm making simple calculator. User inputs simple expression e.g. 1+2 or 11*4 or 24/2.
I need to use case structure to echo calculation like “3 multiplied by 4 equals 12”.
Atm case structure does not echo when running the program?

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Give expression example: 42+6 " calc
read NUM1 NUM2 <<<${calc//[^0-9]/ }

case $calc in
    \+)
    echo "$NUM1 plus $NUM2 equals $NUM1+$NUM2"
    ;;
    \-)
    echo "$NUM1 minus $NUM2 equals $NUM1-$NUM2"
    ;;
    \*)
    echo "$NUM1 multiplied by $NUM2 equals $NUM1*$NUM2"
    ;;
    \/)
    echo "$NUM1 divided by $NUM2 equals $NUM1/$NUM2"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: `case $calc in`: `$calc` is the whole expression no? you need to match it against `*+*` `*-*` `*\**` `*/*`

Comment: Woops, i see. Thank you. How can store operator in variable from expression?E xpression can change so I can't use static index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `$calc` is the raw string of the input

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Give expression example: 42+6 " calc
read NUM1 NUM2 <<<${calc//[^0-9]/ }
read oper <<<${calc//[0-9]/}

case $oper in
    \+)
    echo "$NUM1 plus $NUM2 equals $NUM1+$NUM2"
    ;;
    \-)
    echo "$NUM1 minus $NUM2 equals $NUM1-$NUM2"
    ;;
    \*)
    echo "$NUM1 multiplied by $NUM2 equals $NUM1*$NUM2"
    ;;
    \/)
    echo "$NUM1 divided by $NUM2 equals $NUM1/$NUM2"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!
"read oper <<<${calc//[0-9]/}", where can I read more about this? I don't fully understand that yet.

Comment: @McDreamyh https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626627/what-bash-feature-is-used-when-replacing-strings-in-a-variable-within-curly-brac